# Splitting data in x_train and x_test gives error: Too many values to unpack expected 2

Tags: python, image, train-test-split

Whenever I try to split the data into `x_train` and `x_test` I get the following error:

```
Too many values to unpack expected 2
```

My code:

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

for img in glob.glob("F:/Pics/Training_data/*.jpg"):
  k_images = mpimg.imread(img)
  plt.show()
  plt.imshow(k_images)

  (x_train, _), (x_test, _) = k_images
```

Here `k_images` is of `np.ndarray` type and contains 10 images.

Please tell me what should I change to avoid the error at train, test split of k_images.

Comment: Can you give some example input (`k_images`) and expected output, i.e., how it should be split into train/test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
x_train, x_test = np.array_split(k_images, 2, 2)
```

[Documentation found here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html).

If you're looking into ML I suggest checking out `sklearn`, for example sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split would help you a lot with this, [documentation found here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Comment: Thank you so much it worked and solved my problem.

Comment: @KartikeyaKawadkar Sweet! Good luck, I would appreciate if you marked it as accepted solution!

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the shape of the ndarray is (10,x,y,c)
if you don't care about randomness you can just use pythons list notations

```
x = np.arange(10).reshape((10, 1,1,1))
x_train = x[:8]
x_test = x[8:]
x_train.shape
(8, 1, 1, 1)
x_test.shape
(2, 1, 1, 1)
```

or just use sklearn train_test_split function which is way better and adds randomness to the selection process...

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html